# how to animate concert crowd in blender without animating each individual person?

Tags: makehuman

what would be the best way to do this. im am using make human to make rigged 3d models for the crowd. its going to be focused on the crowd so it needs to look good up close. Right now i am thinking the best way to go through each person and animate them with keyframes but maybe there is a easier way? i want them to move like a crowd at the concert. They are going to be very close to each other

Comment: Not for close up, but: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWq-ZPMhai8

Comment: i seen that before. thats not gonna work for what im doing. mine is up close and i dont want them to all do the same animation.